# Celery: How to store results only for the last chain link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celery-4

I have a task chain:

```py
result = celery.chain(task_a.s(), task_b.s())()
```

I am interested only in result of `task_b()`, however celery saves results of both `task_a()` and `task_b()` to backend.

Is there any way to store the results only for `task_b()`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but based on the docs ([1](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#results-options), [2](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Signature)) 
it should be possible to add `ignore_result=True` parameter to `.s()` calls.

If the above doesn't work then you can always configure the whole task
to not store results (by adding `ignore_result=True` to task class or decorator)

**Important:** as per [Celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/canvas.html#important-notes), tasks used within chords cannot ignore their results.
So while it shouldn't concern chains, it's something to be aware of if you plan to use chords.

Comment: Using `ignore_result=True` as `.s()` parameter does not work. Using it in task definition works. It would be nice to have ability to ignore results of a task for a particular call.

Comment: Try use second task as callback, it's possible with link argument as i mentioned in answer

Answer (score -1):

Try mix [link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks) with [ignore results](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-ignore-result) for first task.

```
add.apply_async((2, 2),ignore_result=True, link=add.s(16))
```

Comment: It does ignore result of the first chain, however there is a caveat: this construction returns the task id of the first called task when we are interested in second one. Also this construction is not convenient when using 2+ chain links.

Comment: yeah, you're right, i wonder ignore results  as task decorator argument will work http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#ignore-results-you-don-t-want . It's allow use task signature where task already ignore results

Comment: Unfortunately, setting ignore results in task definition does not give us any choice any further to keep results or not.

Comment: what you think about move all stuff from task to function and wrap this function with two tasks, one with store results and another without it? it's some kind of hack but should work ;)